# Passing absolute file name to read file in c++

Tags: c++, file, absolute

// I am trying to read a file inside a function by calling the function in main and passing the file name as an argument. It's giving an error in opening the file.But same works fine when I pass the file name directly file("file_name"). Why is it so? Thanks in advance.

```
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
void parse(string file_name)
{
   ifstream file("file_name"); //opens file
   if (!file)
   {  
      cout<<"Cannot open file\n";
      return; 
   }  
   cout<<"File is opened\n";
   file.close(); //closes file
}

int main()
{
   parse("abc.txt"); //calls the parse function
   return;   
}
```

Comment: `ifstream file("file_name");` means open a file with the name `"file_name"`, not the contents of the variable `file_name`.  If you're receiving an error passing a `std::string` and not using C++11 you may need to use `file_name.c_str()`.  Just guessing though since you didn't post the actual error in your question.

Comment: Thanks Ninja. What can be an alternative? what if  I want to read all files present in a folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `file_name` and make sure the file used for input is present in the current working directory (the folder in which your executable is). Also, if you're not using `c++11`, you need to convert the string to `char*` like this :

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void parse(string file_name)
{
   ifstream file(file_name.c_str()); //opens file
   if (!file)
   {  
      cout<<"Cannot open file\n";
      return; 
   }  
   cout<<"File is opened\n";
   file.close(); //closes file
}

int main(){
   string st = "abc.txt";
   parse(st); //calls the parse function
   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: @PrashantGupta Please choose a correct answer and end this Q&A. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `"file_name"`. When quoted, you're commanding the `ifstream` to read the file in the working directory *called* `file_name`. Also, make sure `abc.txt` is in the working directory, which is typically the directory where your executable resides.

```
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
void parse(string file_name)
{
   ifstream file(file_name.c_str()); //opens file (.c_str() not needed when using C++11)
   if (!file)
   {  
      cout<<"Cannot open file\n";
      return; 
   }  
   cout<<"File is opened\n";
   file.close(); //closes file
}

int main()
{
   parse("abc.txt"); //calls the parse function
   return;   
}
```

Comment: I have tried removing quotes I am getting this error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(std::string&)’